# XMonad doesn't clear screen on change of workspace

Tags: xmonad

If I change from workspace `1`, which holds a window, to workspace `2`, which does not, the window from workspace `1` will remain on the screen.  Opening a new window in workspace `2` fixes the problem.  It would be nice to see a blank screen, or wallpaper, instead.

Also, if I close the sole window in a workspace, the window will remain projected on the workspace.

Can anyone help me to configure XMonad correctly to avoid this?

It is simply a visual hiccup.

My `xmonad.hs` is here:
https://github.com/peterbecich/dotfiles/blob/master/xmonad/xmonad.hs#L37

I'm running XMonad on Debian 8.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to simply set a wallpaper.  I did this with `feh`: https://wiki.debian.org/Openbox#Setting_your_background_image_with_feh

Thanks to geekosaur on #xmonad on freenode!